# outline has something strange in makefile

Tags: makefile

Here is a foreach clause in Makefile.

```
$(foreach file, $(OBJS_FEEDBACK) $(OBJS_ASM_FEEDBACK),@echo $(file) >> $(OUT_DIR)/$(LINKER_VIA_FEEDBACK) &)
```

It makes a txt file from the output result.
But, 2nd line has no [CR][LF], so, next line is padded to the 2nd line as below.
I have never seen this before.

```
Build/Feedback/Source/Test/a.o [CR][LF] 
Build/Feedback/Source/Test/b.o  @echo Build/Feedback/Source/Test/c.o [CR][LF] 
Build/Feedback/Source/Test/d.o [CR][LF]
```

How to resolve this something strange?

Comment: Could you post a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this with @ on the head as below.

```
@$(foreach file, $(OBJS_FEEDBACK) $(OBJS_ASM_FEEDBACK),echo $(file) >> $(OUT_DIR)/$(LINKER_VIA_FEEDBACK) &)
```